# How to navigate From one view controller to other

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have problem in navigating from one view controller to other.

what I'm doing is If suppose there are 3 view controllers A,B,C then from A I'm pushing to B.

But in B view did load I'm hitting one api and if status code is not 200 I'm pushing to C.

But my problem is only navigation title of C is appearing and every thing is B's view.

Here is code:

```
 NSLog(@"~~~~~ Status code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);

      NSLog(@"Error: %@", [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode: urlResponse.statusCode]);

    if([urlResponse statusCode]!=200)
    {



      TermsAndConditions * view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TermsAndConditions"];



        self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"";
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: The problem is not in the code you've shared. You should share all relevant code if this is a "I don't know what's wrong" kind of question. Also, try to narrow your problem down some more before you ask next time.

Comment: Provide relevant code as the code you provided is right and also screen shot would also be good to go.

Comment: hey!! are you using storyboard ???

Comment: yes I'musin story board.

Comment: how to upload screen shot

Answer (score 3):

Just drag from a button or any other object to another viewController in stroyboard. it is the simple way.

and the another method is

Import The viewController example: `#include "SecondViewController"`

then define it in .m file where u want to take the navigation

```
 SecondViewController *tempVC =[[SecondViewController alloc]
 initWithNibName:@"homeViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:tempVC animated:YES];
```

but here pushViewController does not carry the navigation properties if u need navigation properties in SecondViewController write like this

```
 SecondViewController *tempVC =[[SecondViewController alloc]
 initWithNibName:@"homeViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController presentedViewController:tempVC animated:YES]
```

it works for your definitely.

Comment: It is working for me. But From there I need to go to Home view controller.Means I'm unable to push from that presented view controller.

Comment: u just confusing. k tell me that what your using for navigation storyboard or xib or programmatically.

Comment: if([urlResponse statusCode]!=200) it means it takes u for another view controller if the the code is not equal to 200 just edit it  if([urlResponse statusCode]=200)

Comment: I want to go  to another view controller if status code is not 200